# Is it haram to have breast enhancement surgery to correct the asymmetry after a lump has been removed?

Tags: halal-haram, women, medical

I want to ask regarding law according to islam about breast enhancement surgery (plastic or fat transfer) for my case. A couple of years ago, I have a breast surgery that I have to remove a lump on my right breast (like breast cancer but its not) and it is due to medical condition and if it is not remove, it can be dangerous for me. After the surgery, my right breast is not the same size or symmetrical-like my left breast. Means that my right breast is smaller than my left breast. I just want to know, is it haram or permissible if I want to do breast enhancement surgery on my right breast up until so that my right breast can be the same size or symmetrical with my left breast or to its original size?

I have been reading that some say its haram but some say due to certain condition it is permissible. I feel like my breast is kinda disfigured because it is not the same size. What I want to do, it is permissible, if I want to do breast enhancement surgery only on my right breast so it can be the same size as before my breast surgery?

Comment: Means that I only can increase my right breast to original size am I right? Is it haram if I want to increase my left breast a bit also?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is permissible.**

According to [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/108860), it is permissible to have breast enhancement surgery to remove faults in the breasts. You have stated that one of your breasts are small which is a fault, so it is permissible for you to have breast enhancement surgery.

> They were also asked (25/59): one of my colleagues had gotten married,
>   praise be to Allaah, but he came to me and said that his wife wants to
>   have cosmetic surgery on her face and breasts, **because her nose is
>   large and wide, and she wants to reduce it** by means of the easy
>   methods that modern science has developed. Is there any doubt about
>   this surgery or is there any sin involved? Please note that not doing
>   it may lead to psychological distress because this fault appears so
>   prominently on her face.
>
> They replied: If the situation is as described, and there is the hope
>   that the surgery will be successful and will not lead to a greater or
>   equal harm, then it is permissible to do it in order to achieve the
>   desired purpose, otherwise it is not permissible.
>
> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) was asked about
>   some cosmetic procedures such as straightening the nose, liposuction,
>   breast reduction or enhancement, and so on – what is the ruling on
>   these procedures? What are the guidelines, may Allaah bless and reward
>   you and benefit others through you.
>
> He replied: With regard to the beautification that you mentioned,
>   beautification is of two types. The first type is done to remove
>   faults and the second type is done to increase beauty. The first type
>   – removing faults – is permissible; if a person’s nose is bent, it is
>   permissible for him to have surgery to straighten it, because this is
>   removing a fault. The nose is not normal, rather it is bent, so he
>   wants to straighten it. The same applies to a man who has a squint;
>   this is undoubtedly a fault, so if he wants to have surgery to correct
>   the fault, it is permissible and there is no reason why he should not,
>   because this is removing a fault.
>
> If a man’s nose is cut off due to an
>   accident, can he have a prosthetic nose installed?
>
> An incident of
>   this type occurred at the time of the Prophet (peace and blessings of
>   Allaah be upon him). The nose of one of the Sahaabah was cut off in
>   battle and the man had a nose of silver made, but the silver tarnished
>   and developed an unpleasant smell, so the Prophet (peace and blessings
>   of Allaah be upon him) gave him permissible to have a nose made of
>   gold, so he did that. Hence we say: is it for beautification or to
>   remove a fault? Removing a fault is permissible. The same applies if
>   the lip is cleft (harelip); it is permissible to join the two sides
>   because this is removing a fault.
>
> [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/108860)

Comment: Means that I only can increase my right breast to original size am I right? Is it haram if I want to increase my left breast a bit also?

Comment: the whole point is that you can ONLY do it if there is necessity (by necessity means there is visible or clear fault, which creates problems for you. Like if husband is irritated by breast size during sex, so in that case, fixing them should be ok)