# Is it haram to have a breast reduction/enlargement surgery?

Tags: halal-haram

I am 15 years old and my breasts are very huge and saggy. Is it permissible for me to have a breast reduction surgery when i get older? Please note that my breasts cause me a great deal of embarrassment and are affecting my daily life.

just to make the question more comprehensible, i would like to know the rulings/arguments for and against both reduction and enlargement. please note that the intention of doing it is not for beauty or show-off. (one may wonder why enlargement then, consider a scenario where the husband requests)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it haram to have breast enhancement surgery to correct the asymmetry after a lump has been removed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/is-it-haram-to-have-breast-enhancement-surgery-to-correct-the-asymmetry-after-a)

Comment: The whole point is that you can ONLY do it if there is necessity (here necessity means there is a genuine health reason, which creates problems for you or your (future) husband)

Comment: @Ahmed can embarrassment and affecting daily life can be considered as a necessity?. can the mental well-being also be considered as a health reason?. these are just a few questions i have regarding this issue and that is the reason why i wanted to see both sides of the arguments. the related questions does not answer these queries. as you have mentioned, i agree on the health reason but what is the scope of it. how do we define what comes under health, only physical or is it more holistic than that. jazaakallah for your opinion.

Comment: @Nazeem Some of these cases require analysis on a case to case basis... it needs to be analyzed if the deterioration of mental health is due to a physiological condition or due to mere peer pressure. While the latter is no joking matter, there is no ijtehad among the ulema if that constitute a 'necessity' ... IMHO the sister should seek professional advice either from a Muslim doctor or a qualified Aalima ... if neither are easily available to her, I'd still recommend her to speak to her mother or some relative who she is comfortable with ... May Allah make it easy on her ... Ameen